# Add to a multi-dimensional array php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array like this:

```
$where = array(
 'product_id' => $product_id,
 'item_id' => $item_id
);
```

I want to add to this array, based on a condition, so I could do

```
if($condition){
 $where = array()
}else{
 $where = array()
}
```

And repeat the original contents twice, but ideally, I'd like to do like an `array_push(array('id' => $id), $where);`

Thanks!

Comment: what exactly do you want as a result?

Answer (score 3):

you may add something to your array in the following way:

```
$where['mykey'] ='myvalue';
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply add it to your array by specifying the index and the value.

```
if($condition){
 $where['id'] = $id;
}else{
 $where['other'] = $other;
}
```